# Utilizing a vectors index number when using map

Tags: r

I have a function which utilizes `purrr::map`. I would like to access the index number of the vector element being used in the map function.

In the example below, I would like to add the index number to each value:

```
library(tidyverse)

c(2, 3) %>% 
  map_dbl(~.x + [index])
```

So, for example, for the first element, `2`, the map function would evaluate and return:

2 + 1 = 3, where 1 = its index in the source vector

Whereas for the second element, `3`, the map function would evaluate and return:

3 + 2 = 5, where 2 = its index in the source vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `map`, use `imap`, which returns the index with `.y` (if not named).  It is mentioned in the documentation of `?imap`

> imap_xxx(x, ...), an indexed map, is short hand for map2(x, names(x), ...) if x has names, or map2(x, seq_along(x), ...) if it does not.

```
c(2, 3) %>% 
    imap_dbl(~ .x + .y )
```

-output

```
[1] 3 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```r
library(tidyverse)

c(2, 3) %>% 
  map2_dbl(1:length(.), ~.x + .y)

#> [1] 3 5
```